# PySide2 How to relaunch run( ) function in second QThread?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

There is some functionality class (let name is FuncClass), which will be moved to QThread (let name it second_thread). FuncClass has the run() function, which connects with second_thread starting event. After some movements, function run() ends, and second_thread continue to live in background up to end the main program. I want to reuse this thread. I want to relaunch the run() function in FuncClass this thread, and i want to do it as fast as possible, but after some event in main_thread only.

As example, i have a chat. From main_thread i create the second_thread (at program start), and move my FuncClass object (chat backend functions)  to this second_thread. I have connection between send_button_click and run() function in the second_thread. After pushing the send button my message will be processed, run() function will reach it's end, second thread will continue working, but, i actually can't restart the run() function with new button_send_click.

(I don't want to use endless loops in run() function, because i don't want to burn my cpu with useless loops, while waiting button_send_click, but i still need high speed response from this function (like activating at first time. ))

And that's why i don't want to use pack of these functions below to restart the thread execution (too long and freezes main_gui).

```
thread.exit() 
thread.wait() 
thread.start()
```

How can i restart the function as fast as possible, without endless check-loops and freezing main_gui?

Comment: If you don't need an event loop for the secondary thread, subclass QThread and override its `run()` instead of using `moveToThread()`.

Comment: i need three thread actually. i'm not sure, that it's good decision to subclass QThread and override run (as official qt doc said 'u can you this move at last resort) . Btw, i dont clearly understand event_loop in thread. Is event-loop foing to be deleted, if i moveToThread, or it deletes when subclass only? (sorry my english ._.) And is it actually possible to relaunch the function with moveToThrad?

Comment: No, the documentation suggests both approaches, depending on the situation. When you use `moveToThread()`, the thread (along with its event loop) runs until it's explicitly quit, and that's why you can't restart it. Generally speaking, if you don't need to process events and incoming signals that must call the slot in the thread, you can safely use a QThread subclass (especially considering the python implementation). An alternative is to create a `finished()` signal for the worker class, emit it when you are exiting the `run()` and connect it with the `QThread.quit` slot.

Comment: in my app i have this system: main thread, which ll collect my message text and send it to the FuncClass (where i want to restart run() ). Butm i need to collect an answers from my backend (from FuncClass), so, i have a slot in the second_thread, which (slot) adds answer into my chat display

Comment: Note that there's some confusion caused by a couple of [in]famous posts that date back a lot of years. While their intent was right, considering many aspects (most importantly, the age of those posts and the fact that threading in Python doesn't work exactly in the same way as in C++), the assumption that subclassing QThread is wrong is a *wrong* assumption. That said, what you probably need is a continuous loop that imitates an event loop, implement a Queue (which you'll use to send messages) and periodically check for items in that Queue or otherwise emit signals based on server response.